# Use greater than operator on ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `ng-show` on a div. I have tried the below code but does not seem to work.

```
<div style="color:red; font-size:small" ng-show="a > {{b}}">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean show when a > b ?

Answer (score 0):

The expression given to `ng-show` already uses the context of the current scope. There's no need to do template interpolation (i.e., `{{b}}`).

Just do:

```
<div style="color:red; font-size:small" ng-show="a > b">Hello</div>
```

And that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy

```
<div style="color:red; font-size:small" ng-show="a > b">Hello</div>
```